# Catch user defined URLs in UrlManager

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have the ability for users to define URLs for some of their items so, for example:

```
http://x.com/mynewobject
```

`mynewobject` would be defined by the user in a form and I need to be able to say in the `UrlManager` to math that, but also match everything else.

Problem is the default rules in the `UrlManager` will try and catch the `mynewobject` controller and throw a 404 when it cannot.

What is the way to make a `UrlManager` catch user defined URLs?

Comment: what you have currently in your config to handle this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found of doing this, without manually declaring your URLs, is to actually take a closer look at the Yii 2 documentation.

It actually shows a good example here of user generated URLs http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#creating-rules which I used to complete my task.

The configuration I used was:

```
'urlManagerFrontend' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'cache' => null,
    'baseUrl' => '/',
    'rules' => [

        [
            'class' => 'common\components\ObjectUrlRule',
            'pattern' => '<slug:.*>',
            'route' => 'site/index'
        ],

        '<controller:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/<action:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:[\w-]+>/<action:[\w-]+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        // your rules go here
    ]
],
```

And a rule class of:

```
<?php

namespace common\components;

use Yii;
use yii\web\UrlRule;
use common\models\ObjectUrl;

class ObjectUrlRule extends UrlRule
{
    public function parseRequest($manager, $request)
    {
        $pathInfo = trim($request->getPathInfo());
        if(!$pathInfo){
            return false;
        }

        $controller = Yii::$app->createController($pathInfo);
        if($controller){
            return false;
        }

        $objectUrl = ObjectUrl::find()->where(['url' => $pathInfo])->one();
        if(!$objectUrl){
            return false;
        }

        return $objectUrl->getUrl($pathInfo);
    }
}
```

Where `ObjectUrl` is the model (table) which contains the map of user generated URLs.

The good thing about this class, as well, is that it will not run the database call unless the controller does not exist and there is a pathinfo.

Comment: `mynewobject` is stored in the database. When you create the controller using the code `$controller = Yii::$app->createController($pathInfo);` the `$controller` is always `false` as the controller named `mynewobject` is not in the controller map. Thus the code won't execute further. Correct me if I am wrong. But you will have to check the DB for the url and then return the parameter if the `ObjectUrl` exist. Something like `return ['site/index', ['objectUrlId' => $objectUrl->id]]`. Where in the GET param you get the `id` in your `site/index` action.

Comment: Exactly this code will only run if controller is false since this rule runs first thing it needs to not consume rules that already exist